# Proving equivalence between two distributions?

Tags: probability, distributions, combinatorics

I have a simple fully connected graph with $N$ nodes and hence $\binom{N}{2}$ edges. I am asked to colour this fully connected graph, where I pick the colour for the nodes w.r.t a Multinomial Distribution:
$$c \sim Mult(1,\boldsymbol{\theta})$$
Where $\boldsymbol{\theta} = (\theta_1,...,\theta_C)$ is the prior probabilities on the colours.

Now, given two nodes such that $c$ has colour $i$, and $d$ has colour $j$ I colour the edge between them with respect to another Multinomial Distribution:
$$e(c,d) \sim Mult(1,\boldsymbol{\theta^{ij}}) $$

where $\boldsymbol{\theta^{ij}} = (\theta^{ij}_1,...,\theta^{ij}_E)$ are the probabilies for selecting an edge colour from the possible $E$ colours given that
the nodes are coloured $i$ and $j$.

So the probability of observing a graph $g$ with $k_i$ nodes of colour $i$ and $h^{ij}_v$ edges of colour $v$, between nodes coloured $i$ and $j$ is:

$$P(g) = \prod_{i} (\theta_i)^{k_i}\prod_{1\leq i\leq j\leq C}\prod_{1\leq v \leq E} (\theta^{ij}_{v})^{h^{ij}_v} \tag{1}$$

Where $\boldsymbol{k}(i,j)$ counts the number of edges between nodes coloured $i$ and $j$, hence $$\boldsymbol{k}(i,j) =\begin{cases} k_ik_j , &i\ne j  \\
                     \frac{ k_i(k_i-1)}{2}, &i=j\end{cases}$$
and $\sum_v h^{ij}_v = \boldsymbol{k}(i,j)$

---

Alternative description of the same distribution:

This time I don't have a hierarchical generative model but rather a distribution defined by weights:

A node coloured $i$ has a weight $w_i$ and an edge coloured $v$ between two nodes coloured $i$ and $j$ have a weight $w^{ij}_v$ hence the weight of a graph $g$ is $\prod_{i} (w_i)^{k_i}\prod_{1\leq i\leq j\leq C}\prod_{1\leq v \leq E} (w^{ij}_{v})^{h^{ij}_v}$ and $P(g)$ is given as :

$$\frac{\prod_{i} (w_i)^{k_i}\prod_{1\leq i\leq j\leq C}\prod_{1\leq v \leq E} (w^{ij}_{v})^{h^{ij}_v}}{Z} \tag{2}$$
Where $Z$ is the sum of weights of all graph colourings.Formally:

$$Z = \sum_{g:{\sum_{i}k_i = N}\\{g:\sum_{v}h^{ij}_v = \boldsymbol{k}(i,j) } }\prod_{i} (w_i)^{k_i}\prod_{1\leq i\leq j\leq C}\prod_{1\leq v \leq E} (w^{ij}_{v})^{h^{ij}_v}$$

---

QUESTION: Intuitively I think any distribution described by $(2)$ can be described as $(1)$ and vice versa, the vice-versa direction is trivial, as you just put $\theta_i$ equal to $w_i$ and $\theta^{ij}_v$ equal to $w^{ij}_v$ and $Z$ is trivially equal to 1. But going from $(2)$ to $(1)$ is not so trivial ! My idea was to figure out a reparameterisation for $w_i$ and $w^{ij}_v$ for example setting $\theta_i = \frac{w_i}{\sum_i w_i}$ and  $\theta^{ij}_v = \frac{w^{ij}_v}{\sum_v w^{ij}_v}$ and put it in $(1)$ to get the same probability distribution but at this point I am quite sure this is incorrect, Is there a easier way to show their equi-expressivity ?

---

Please let me know in comments if anything is not clear.

Comment: What do you assume about the $w_i, w_{ij}$? I guess you want them to be positive, but they may not be in $[0,1]$ and you don't want to assume that they sum up to 1, right? I gather that $Z$ is the sum over all $g$ of the stuff in the numerator, correct (it may help if you write down $Z$ formally)?

Comment: @ChristianHennig you are right, $\{w_i\}$ are positive reals $[0,\infty)$ and $Z$ is exactly as you described.

Comment: I suspect that this is not true. What I'd do with more time is trying to construct an as simple as possible counterexample. The smallest example has two colors, two nodes, and one edge, although it may be that two edges are required for a counterexample. I'd then use weights 1 and 2 or 1 and 3 and write down all of the numerators in (2) and their sum (this takes too much time for me to do, sorry). I suspect that one can then see that this can *not* be emulated in form (1), but of course I can't be sure without having tried. (Otherwise trying this may give you an idea for a proof.)

Comment: @ChristianHennig Thanks for the comments, I will definitely try the proposed approach. But I am curious as (intuitively) why do u think they are not equi-expressive, the underlying probability space is the same and the degrees of freedoms also are the same i.e. the graph is fully connected and you have to colour all the edges and nodes  with same  number of colours ?

Comment: Numbers larger than 1 behave differently from probabilities when taking powers. So I suspect that ratios between probabilities in (2) if you have weights larger than 1 may differ from those that you get from the multinomial model (1). But this is a rather weak suspicion, I may be wrong.

Comment: @ChristianHennig I think you are right, an example is: let us pick a distribution in (1) and assume that $\theta^{ij}_1 = 1$ for all $ i \leq j$ and hence $\theta^{ij}_v = 0$ for all $v \neq 1$. Now lets take a distribution $(2)$ such that $w_i = \theta_i$ , $w^{ij}_v = \theta^{ij}_v$ for $ i   \leq j$ except that $w^{11}_1 = 10^{6}$. I think this distribution cannot be expressed as (1).

Comment: Looks fine to me. Nice way of constructing a counterexample without going through lots of cases.

Comment: @ChristianHennig On further analysis, I realised that I am not sure if the example I gave is a real counter- example. And I think the procedure of re-parameterisation may go like this: query the distribution with weights for P(an arbitrary node is coloured i) and put this value equal to $\theta_i$, similarly query the weighted distribution for conditional probability of edge colour given node colours and put it equal to $\theta^{ij}_v$ but the problem is how do I prove that P(an arbitrary node is coloured i) and P(an arbitrary node is coloured j) are independent in the weighted model?